# Empty response while scraping a coupon code website (slickdeals)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape coupon code details from slickdeals. Below is my code for one of the stores (1800 petmeds):

```
def start_requests(self):
    store_url = "https://slickdeals.net/coupons/1-800-petmeds/"
    yield scrapy.Request(url=store_url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    for coupon in response.xpath("//div[@class='storeItems all']/div/div/a"):
        yield {
            'title': coupon.xpath(".//div/span/text()").extract_first(),
            'type': coupon.xpath(".//div/div[1]/span[1]/text()").extract_first(),
            'code': coupon.xpath(".//@data-clipboard-text").extract_first(),
            'category': response.xpath("//div[@class='main']/h1/text()").extract_first()
        }
```

However, I get back an empty output .json file (no error is shown in the terminal line). 
Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visit the page source [page source](http://view-source:https://slickdeals.net/coupons/1-800-petmeds/), then you will see that there is no class with name

> storeItems all

Please check the DOM if you are using scrapy only.

You can try to change your xpath according to whats appearing on DOM.

Comment: Ohh it worked with a different class ('boxContent'). Actually 'storeItems all' class name was showing when I inspected the coupon elements. Thanks btw!

Comment: @ArAg Would you please accept the answer if it worked. Thanks